# Retrieve datas from anilist api

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm developping a small next.js app and I tried to fetch from an API (https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/). Because I want to display a set of Anime's cover.

To do so I had to use graphQl. First I would like to manage to display the name of some animes. To practice the use of graphQl in next.js I followed the tutorial on [this page](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/next-js/next-js-getting-started/). All went good I had no problem, so I tried with the anilist api but I did not succeed I tried to log data as deep as I can, but not as I wanted.

When I log by doing `console.log(medias)` I do manage to log the wanted informations. But when it comes to apply this to display each values I turn around. If you have an idea i'll appreciate.
Thanks for helping =)

This is the code:

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const QUERY = gql`
  query GetFirstsThree{
    Page(page: 1, perPage: 3) {
    media {
      id
      coverImage {
        medium
      }
      title {
        userPreferred
      }
    }
  }
  }
`;

export default function AnimList() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }

  const medias = data.Page.media;

  return (
    <div className="mainGrid">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    
    {medias.map((value) => {
      <div key={value.id} className="card">
      <h3>
        {value.title.userPreferred}
      </h3>
      </div>
    })}

    </div>
    );
  }
```

[image: log from query]

Answer (score 1):

The variable `medias` contains array and not an object. So instead of

```js
Object.keys(medias).map(...
```

you need to do just

```js
medias.map(...
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it works fine but still it do not display the title and this the keypoint of my topic. :/

Comment: @PazzeG you should be doing `{value.title.userPreferred}` to show the title

Comment: Logging {value.title.userPreferred} works but displaying it don't.

Comment: wow, I didn't even notice that nothing was returned in that `map` function. You can skip the `return` statement altogether and just write
```typescript
{medias.map((value) => (<div key={value.title.userPreferred} className="card"><p>{value.title.userPreferred}</p></div>
))}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip I didn't know =)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. The titles wasn't displayed because I didn't return them Thanks everyone for helping me

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const QUERY = gql`
  query GetFirstsThree{
    Page(page: 1, perPage: 3) {
    media {
      id
      coverImage {
        medium
      }
      title {
        userPreferred
      }
    }
  }
  }
`;

export default function AnimList() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }

  const medias = data.Page.media;
console.log(medias)


  return (
    <div className="mainGrid">
   
    
    {medias.map((value) => {
//  It just needed the return like below

      return <div key={value.title.userPreferred} className="card">
      
      <p>{value.title.userPreferred}</p>  
      
      </div>
    })}

    </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is good idea to share how do you correct your problem with others. I have found the answer, and bunch of code, will not help others.

Comment: I just had a comment in the answer hope it helps